# How to find the subject in a text?

Tags: algorithm, natural-language-processing, ai-basics, getting-started

I often develop bots and I need to understand what some people are saying.

Examples:
- I want an apple
- I want an a p p l e

How do I find the object (*apple*)? I honestly don't know where to start looking. Is there an API that I can send the text to which returns the object? Or perhaps I should manually code something that analyses the grammar?

Answer (score 1):

It depends on the complexity on your sentences. If you have a limited range, you could do simple pattern matching on part-of-speech tags. Put your sentence through a tagger (there are plenty of them around) and look for the first noun following a verb:

```
I       want an         apple
Pronoun verb determiner noun
```

(I assume you mean the **object**, as the subject in that sentence would be *I*). Scan through the list until you hit a verb, then pick the next noun. This should work for most English sentences.

It gets a bit more complicated if your nouns have additional words around them, for example *red apple* (where *red* is an adjective) or *bottle of beer* (where you have the pattern `noun OF noun`). So if you want to capture those fully, you might need a few more complex matching rules.

Overall it should still be a lot easier than implementing a full-blown syntactic parser which creates a comprehensive structural analysis of your sentence, most of which you wouldn't need in the first place.

Comment: I'm trying to do something similar to this.  I would like to perform sentiment analysis, however I need to keep track of the subject, so I can be aware of what the sentiment applies to.   using SVO, to manually parse it might work, what would you reccomend?

Comment: Depends how precise it has to be. You can get quite far with simple heuristics, but every percentage accuracy in precision beyond say, 70-80 percent,  requires a lot more effort.

Comment: Thanks, I'm going to try a hybrid solution.  use AI to find the subject using a syntax parser, and then some list of rules to see if the subject from the previous sentence is the same

Comment: That sounds like a good approach.